# CSS / HTML: How to force horizontal scrollbar when table does not fit on screen?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I have a large table in landscape format that requires to have a minimum width for each column (see below) in order for the columns to stay wide enough for proper inputs.

Due to this I need to force a horizontal scrollbar to appear when this minimum size has been reached instead of further shrinking of the table's columns.

The table has 15 columns in total and uses a colgroup, the first column has the class "`col1`", the second one has "`col2`" and all others have "`col3`" to apply the styles.

I then tried to add the following styles but the **table is still being shrinked further and I am not getting the required horizontal scrollbar** when testing with a smaller screen size.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?
Would it make more sense to use `@ media screen` here ?

**My CSS:**

```
#myTable {
    font-size: 14px;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#myTable .col1 {
    width: 35px;
}
#myTable .col2 {
    min-width: 180px;
}
#myTable .col3 {
    min-width: 108px;
    width: 6.5%;
}
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: Try wrapping the table in a div and add `overflow-x` on the div.

Comment: What about putting the table in a scrolling container

Comment: will be very helpful if you can pass a full example through [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/?html) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) also in your question  you can put an example with the HTML and CSS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the table in a div and set everything there.

```
<div id="tableWrapper">
    <table id="myTable">
       <tr>
           ...
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h037abq3/24/

Comment: Thanks ! I tried this but it doesn't change anything in my case.

Comment: Thanks again. I figured this out - I had to twist some other things as well but this pointed me in the right direction so I accept this as the answer. :)